# How to send a curl request to timekit.io API

Tags: rest, http, curl

I am trying to follow the documentation from [timekit.io](http://timekit.io). I am attempting to do something as simple as send a curl request to do basic authentication as seen in [this section](http://developers.timekit.io/docs/authentication#section-client-side-authentication) of the docs. I have replaced the `Timekit-App:name-of-app` with the name of my app which I found in the app-settings of my timekit account. I also replaced the `email` & `password` with the one's I use to login into my account.

I simply copied and pasted the curl command as is into my terminal and I get a response that says `{"error":"Content-type should be json!"}` I am not sure if I am not supposed to copy and paste it as is, or what I may be doing wrong, but my understanding is I am supposed to get a json response with a `email` and a `api` token among some other data.

Here is my curl command.

```
curl -X POST \
   -H 'Timekit-App: jl-fit' \
   -d '{
         "email": "email@email.com",
         "password": "password"
       }' \
   https://api.timekit.io/v2/auth
```

Comment: Try adding `-H 'Content-Type: application/json'`. Looks like a bug in their docs.

Comment: Would you like to post that as a answer so I could select it as the solution.

Comment: Sure, if that solves it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have discovered a bug in their docs/examples.

The API you're connecting to expects JSON content type, but `curl` by default (for `POST`ing data) uses `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. You can fix it by adding the header field explicitly with: `-H 'Content-Type: application/json'`.

Also, when you use the `-d`/`--data` option, method defaults to `POST`, so it doesn't have to be specified explicitly.

All put together, this should work:

```
curl \
   -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
   -H 'Timekit-App: jl-fit' \
   -d '{"email": "email@email.com", "password": "password"}' \
   "https://api.timekit.io/v2/auth"
```

When having multiple arguments, it can be convenient to keep them in an array (no need to escape newlines). For example:

```
args=(
   -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
   -H 'Timekit-App: jl-fit'
   -d '{"email": "email@email.com", "password": "password"}'
   "https://api.timekit.io/v2/auth"
)
curl "${args[@]}"
```